# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

this is the `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^/', include('main.urls', namespace='Home')),

]
```

this is the `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse,render_to_response,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from main.models import *

class leaflet(TemplateView):
    template_name = "file.html"
```

When I wrote this code template not showing, it throws an error:

> `__init__()` takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

could you find the error in my code?

Comment: can you put all traceback?

Comment: and can you give us django version? since if it's django 2.x, namesapces are defined in app's urls.py with `app_name` variable and namespace inclusion in url function is removed

Comment: What's main.urls look like? your view isn't even referenced in the urls.py you gave. And yes, post the traceback please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add leaflet.as_view() in urlpatterns

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from main.views import leaflet

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
   url(r'^/', include('main.urls', namespace='Home')),
   url(r'^test/', leaflet.as_view()),
]
```

Answer (score -1):

You `urls.py` should be look like

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^/', include('main.urls'), name='Home'),

]
```

Updated:
If you are using django-version 1.8 or earlier, you should add `app_name` argument in `include` function

```
url(r'^/', include('main.urls', namespace='Home', app_name='polls'))
```

Comment: this doesn't make sense, name may not be passed to url function, so, this doesn't explain the problem!

Comment: name is passed to give a name to url so that it can be called from Reverse method. It is good practice to give name to each url

Comment: Yeah this has nothing to do with his issue. Somewhere, he's calling a constructor wrong.

Comment: totally agree that it's good practice, but your answer does not solves the problem, which is the goal of the answer, it's just recommendation, which does not help in any way, I think

Comment: @IanKirkpatrick i think this is django version problem (please, see my comment on question)